# Keras Finding the best loss among multiple losses from multiple outputs for backpropagation

Tags: python, keras, loss-function

I am using a multiple output model in keras for a regression problem.

For example the model is like :

```
model = Model(inp, [out1, out2, out3])
```

I want to calculate loss of each output but based on each loss, select one and backpropagate only through that and make every other weights 0. It is like a loss that finds the best loss and output among all loss and learns only through that output.

For example, out 1 loss was minimum, so my weight will be [1.0, 0.0, 0.0],so that model will not learn anything from out2 and out3.

size of out1, out2 and out3 are same.

I am not so experienced with keras, is there any way to do it.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple output models are documented in:
https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#multi-input-and-multi-output-models

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of this. Technically, I want to back propagate only though one output. But that output will be chosen based on loss of all outputs. Whichever loss is minimum I will choose that out put and backpropagate though that by making weight of every other out branch to be 0. So I know i how to calculate loss of multiple outputs, but i want to find the minimum of loss among them and then decide weights accordingly. @PedroMarques

Comment: Have you considered what behaviour you want in a batch ? e.g. suppose that for 10 samples the loss of output 0 is lower and for 10 other samples the loss of output1 is the lower loss ? which of the weights do you want to set to 0 ?  What is the intuition behind what you are trying achieve ? What is wrong with just accepting all the losses ?